# iPhone changing swipe to delete button title

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I get that you need to use the following method and return what you want the new title to be as an NSString. However I don't know where to put this method. Where is it normally placed?

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
   titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return @"Close";
}
```

I've tried it in my **TableViewController** and it doesn't work:

### interface

```
#import <Three20/Three20.h>

@interface PositionsController : TTTableViewController {
}

@end
```

### implementation

```
#import "PositionsController.h"
#import "NetworkController.h"
#import "PositionsDataSource.h"

@implementation PositionsController

- (id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.variableHeightRows = NO;
    }

    return self;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return @"Close";
}

@end
```

I won't put all the code in there, nevertheless everything functions as it should but I still get **Delete** as the title for my button and not **Close**.

## Three20 Library Revised Working Code

The problem I was having is that I was using the **TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate** for my **UITableView's** delegate. I was doing so via the following method:

```
- (id<UITableViewDelegate>)createDelegate {
        return [[[TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate alloc] initWithController:self] autorelease];
}
```

That's all well and good but if you want to override a method that the **UITableViewDelegate** calls, like what I was trying to do here, then you need to create your own delegation class that inherits **TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate** and put your method overrides in that class. Here is what my working code looks like:

### Revised PositionsController.m createDelegate method

```
- (id<UITableViewDelegate>)createDelegate {
     return [[[PositionsTableDelegate alloc] initWithController:self] autorelease];
 }
```

### PositionsTableDelegate.h

```
#import <Three20/Three20.h>


@interface PositionsTableDelegate : TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate <UITableViewDelegate> {

}

@end
```

### PositionsTableDelegate.m

```
#import "PositionsTableDelegate.h"


@implementation PositionsTableDelegate

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return @"Close";
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a delegate method of UITableView. You need to implement it in the class which instance is set as the delegate of your TableView.

Try to set the `delegate`-property of the TableView to the instance of `PositionsController`.

Comment: Okay that along with addind <UITableViewDelegate> to the PositionsController.h file did it. I have some formatting issues, but this is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The method that you are using is defined for UITableViewDelegate, so you need to define it for a class that is the delegate for your UITableView.

Comment: He doesn't want to disable swipe-to-delete, he wants to change the title of the button.

Comment: Kind of quick on the down vote. I was in the process of editing answer, having just realized that I had misread question.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I don't know if TTTableController is doing anything different so you're problem may lie there.

The function you're using only effects the button's title on the actual cell (ie swipe to delete, or after the user had tapped the minus button), not the Edit button above the `tableView`.

If you want to change the button above your `tableView` I believe you will need to create your own button and implement the `setEditing:animated:` functionality yourself.

See here for more info: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Edit:
The function you're using should be in the `TableView`'s delegate.

Comment: Yes, I want to change it on the actual cell, and my best guess is that the 320 library might handle things differently. But I'm new to this, so my best guess isn't much.

Comment: OK I don't use the 320 library for reasons such as this!  I would start by double checking that your titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath is actually being called.